# facebook like button doesn't work correctly

Tags: facebook-like

I have installed a number of facebook like buttons using the og method. The button redirects to a page containing the correct metadata. I have checked this page using the facebook debug tool and it shows no errors. However, when I click on the facebook button it changes to 'Confirm' and when I click it I get a dialogue that is visually OK. I click 'Like' and the dialogue disappears and then the normal dropdown appears under the button. I then click 'Post to facebook' but nothing happens and the dropdown remains in view until I click Close or refresh the page.

See for example http://www.rupertheath.com/books/clarke01 with the facebook like button at the bottom of the page.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to find the answer to your question here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/412902132095994/

Comment: Thanks for that Luz - The buttons appear to be working again now so I guess it was a Facebook bug issue